# COMO FAZER CÁLCULO DENTRO DE UMA CLASSE? C#

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo o seguinte programa em C#:

Crie uma classe abstrata de nome "Análise Combinatória", responsável por especificar, além do cálculo do fatorial de um número, os métodos devidos para Cálculo de Permutações, Arranjos e Combinações de elementos[...]

Preciso fazer uma classe chamada Análise combinatória em que devo realizar o cálculo do fatorial de um número que vai ser digitado pelo usuário no programa principal.

Eu sei como fazer o fatorial, mas dentro de uma classe, vc nem é livre para fazer qualquer tipo de contas igual no static void Main.

Esse aí é o método que eu já fiz:

```
public abstract class AnaliseCombinatoria
    {
        static int Fatorial(int numero)
        {
            for(int i = 0; numero <= 1; i--)
            {
                return numero * (numero - 1);
            }
        }

    }
```

Está dando um erro na variável "Fatorial" dizendo: "AnaliseCombinatoria.Fatorial(int)": nem todos os caminhos de código retornam um valor

Como faz para fazer cálculos dentro de uma classe?

Comment: David, sua pergunta está vaga. Poderia nos mostrar o que já tem e exemplificar o que quer fazer?

Comment: Coleguinha, seu erro não tem a ver com ser de outra classe ou não.

1 - Você disse que você não é livre para fazer as cálculos em uma classe como você é livre na `main`. Mas a `main`está dentro de uma classe também, que você provavelmente deu o nome de `Inicializador` ou algo do tipo.

2 - Seu erro é simples de resolver. 
 `static int Fatorial(int numero) {
  
  for (int i = 0; numero <= 1; i--) {
   
   return numero * (numero - 1);
  }
  
  return numero; // É só por esse return aqui que a IDE vai parar de reclamar
 }`

Comment: As vezes, quando aparecer uma linha vermelha ou amarela, embaixo do seu código, você aperta `Ctrl + 1` (Se estiver no Eclipse) que ele vai te dar umas opções de como resolver determinado problema. No seu caso, a IDE está reclamando que seu método não está retornando um valor em todos os casos possíveis, até porque, se a sua variável `numero` for `Maior ou igual a 1`, não vai fazer nada no `FOR` e seu método não iria retornar nada, e é obrigado a retornar alguma coisa.

Comment: Primeiro, vc está dando um return dentro do loop for ou seja o primeiro calculo irá parar pois o return dentro de um loop ou qualquer linha de execução termina o comando, remova o return  para fora do loop.

Answer (score 1):

Erro em questão é referente ao retorno dentro do Loop;

Coloque assim:

```
static int Fatorial(int numero)
    {
        for(int i = 0; numero <= 1; i--)
        {
            numero = numero * (numero - 1);
        }
        return numero;
    }
```